# After writing to a place in mmapped memory, when printing it out afterwards, it's not written anymore

Tags: c, mmap

I'm trying to mmap a bunch of integers in a multdimensional array into mmapped memory. I know the calculations work because I printed out the multidimensional array and it prints the correct values. And I compared the values in the double for loop, printing the value of the multidimensional array and the value at the place in mmapped memory after it's been assigned, and they both correspond to the same values.

When I leave the for loop and print out what's in the mmapped memory, only the first and last values print correctly. In contrast, when I print out the multidimensional array directly, it does print the correct values. Am I writing to the mmapped memory wrong?

Comment: Can you remove the line numbers and post all of `main`?

Comment: Post `create_mmap_mem()` and the arguments passed to them.  Right now, your posted code is not complete.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this

```
199          args->shmem3[r+c] = m[r][c];
```

Is what you want.  Rather:

```
199          args->shmem3[r*args->matrix_size+c] = m[r][c];
```